# Do I need to play any Middle-Earth games before Shadow of Mordor?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I am a huge fan of LOTR and now after all the hobbits and LOTR movies, I was looking for games based on LOTR and I found wiki [Middle-earth in video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_in_video_games). Now in the List of video games many games are listed but I own a win 10 PC and looking at the latest windows game series "Middle-earth: Shadow of Mordor"'s gameplay, it is just superb.

Can I buy it straight away or should I first go for some previous selected games in the series for a better experience and story experience?

Comment: @RookieTEC9 The question is basicly asking "Is there a reason to play the games in spesific order?" and/or "Is there a reason not to play Shadow of Mordor first?" I find both of these answerable without having to reply on subjective opinnions or personal preferences.

Comment: Further to what @DJPirtu is saying, a quick search of the site reveals numerous similar questions still open (although some have received negative scores whilst some positive).

Comment: they all stand-alone  game with their own story, they just use LOTR element and lore for attracting fan to play.

Comment: @DJ Pirtu I see your point. The question is asking about the story of the games, and whether or not the story starts from the game.

Comment: I removed the suggested-order tag as it borders on being a meta tag and while it may work on other sites, it doesn't fit with how Arqade specifically approaches tagging.

Answer (score 4):

## Simple answer

You can buy *Middle-earth: Shadow of Mordor* straight away.

## More detailed answer

There really is no reason to play the games in a specific order, they have very little in common. storywise, they all are pretty much completely independent from each other.

What I know about the games in this list:
Fellowship, Two Towers and Return of the king (2002-2003) are third person action games, which follow the movies fairly closely.
Battle for Middle-earth 1 and 2 are great RTS games, whereas the first is close to the events of the books/movies, while the second looks at other parts of tolkiens mythology. Both feature a mode, where you can conquer the whole of middle earth (similar to the total war series). Despite being a series, the games really don't have anything to do with each other in terms of the story they tell.
However as EAs license for LotR games expired it may be very hard to get a hold of those games.

War of the ring(2003) is not based on the movies, but the general tolkien license, it's a new story, but I haven't played the game.

War in the north(2011) is an action oriented-rpg featuring a storyline not covered in the main books or books. It's nice for a fan, but the game is nothing spectacular.

Guardians of Middle-Earth(2012) is a moba(think league of legends or dota), I haven't played it, so I can't tell anything more about it.

Shadow of Mordor(2014) is a 3rd person open world action game in the vein of assassins creed. The story isn't covered in the books or movies. It's a very good game with a great feature in the nemesis system, but like AC-games it suffers from being incredibly easy.

The big one is Lord of the rings online. It features a massive game world, a long sotryline quest series, which touch both new ground and elements from the main book series. It's a wealth of content to explore, but of course it is an MMORPG with all its drawbacks and trappings.

I can't say anything about other titles in the list.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that while all MMORPGs have common features, there are certain aspects of some that don't apply to all. Especially when taking into account the MMORPG poster child from Blizzard. For example it might be worth pointing out, that since LotRO has very little focus on PvP and "end game", it tends not to draw the types of players that demand such features. For better or worse, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Shadow of Mordor is a *very* fun game, and they give you everything you really need to know in cut-scenes and in the intro.  Strangely, the *less* you know about Tolkien's universe, the happier you'll be playing it, as there are a number of glaring disconnects with established lore that are very likely to jolt you out of the narrative.  See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70777/how-well-does-shadow-of-mordor-fit-into-middle-earth-canon for details.

If you are very familiar with Middle Earth and it's lore, just do your best to shut down that portion of your brain and just enjoy the experience.

Comment: I'll have to disagree with your statement "the less you know, the happier you'll be" - that's just opinion based. I'm a huge fan of the LOTR series, has some knowledge in the lore, and greatly enjoyed Shadow of Mordor .

Comment: @Wondercricket, Like I said, it's a *very* fun game.  But the repeated contradictions and disconnects with established lore (see edits) had the annoying tendency to shake me out of the narrative.